# Making a view readonly?

Tags: list-view, module

I have a module that deploys a site page "Archives".

I want to set up this page to show the content of a list readonly, whatever permissions are granted to the connected user.

I have build this module :

```
<File Name="archives.aspx"
      Path="spstd4.aspx"
      Url="archives.aspx"
      Type="GhostableInLibrary">
  <View BaseViewID="1"
        DisplayName="Archives"
        List="archives"
        WebPartOrder="0"
        WebPartZoneID="Body"
        ReadOnly="True"
        Type="HTML"/>
</File>
```

The readonly attribute of the view node does not seems to have any effect.

Can I have a view to a list in full readonly mode?

Comment: Is the view in the list itself, on which this one is based, readonly? It could be that it inherits that setting, ignoring yours completely.

Comment: The view in the list is not readonly. I'll try to create a new view in the list with ro

Comment: even on the list itselft, the readonly attribute has no effect...

Comment: which sharepoint version is it ?

Comment: 2010 With Enterprise CAL

Comment: Documentation says it's supposed to be "TRUE" instead of "True". Don't think that'll matter, but I've seen even weirder things happening with SharePoint :)

Comment: Just to be sure, I change to TRUE, but still the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a couple years late, but I think read only on the list view just says that the view itself (what fields are shown, filtering/sorting options, etc.) are read only. It has not control over the data being displayed.